# login into local FTP server with ip

Tags: python

I am trying to log into a FTP server that I am only running locally in my network. To do this I have to use my ip address to use as the server address (see code below). However each time I get a ***gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed*** error.

Can anyone look at my code and see if I am making any error that may be the cause of this address issue? Also I can log into the ftp server fine from my browser so I know the server is up and running correctly, also anonymous login to the server is allowed .

```
#import the ftp lib.
from ftplib import FTP
#enter the address of the ftp server to use, use ip address since server is ran locally
ftp = FTP('ftp://192.168.1.130')
#logs into the ftp server
ftp.login()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're including the protocol with the hostname which is incorrect. What's happening is the library is trying to resolve "ftp://192.168.1.130" (instead of "192.168.1.130"), which isn't a valid address.

```
#Wrong
ftp = FTP('ftp://192.168.1.130')
#Right
ftp = FTP('192.168.1.130')
```

http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [ftplib documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html%20%22ftplib%20documentation), you shoud just give him the host address/IP, and not a string representing an URL. So here, you should simply do:

```
ftp = FTP('192.168.1.130')
```